# how to apply a format on multiple excel files at once (hide gridlines & autofit columns)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to apply a specific format on an iterate excel files, i need to hide the gridlines and autofit columns width, i tried many codes and styles but no one of them worked with me.

the exported excel files shown as below PS[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK6Jm.png)

```
FP_sheet=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Mahmoud.Bader\Desktop\FP Attendance V1.6 Apr 22.xlsx","Attendance").fillna("")
FP_sheet['Date']=pd.to_datetime(FP_sheet['Date']).dt.date

    
dep = FP_sheet["Department"].unique()
#x=('Customer Care','Retail Customer Care','Social Media')
for i in dep:
    FP_Attendance = FP_sheet[FP_sheet["Department"].str.contains(i)]
    FP_Attendance=FP_Attendance.style.set_properties(**{'color':'black','text-align': 'center','font-family': 'Arial Narrow','border-color':'Black','border-width':'thin','border-style':'solid','vertical-align': 'middle'})
    with pd.ExcelWriter(f"C:\\Users\\Mahmoud.Bader\\Desktop\\Python\\Workforce Reports\\FP Test\\{i}.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        FP_Attendance.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=str(i), index=False,freeze_panes=(1,0))
```

Comment: Maybe work with templates? It’s easy. Check this out! 
https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't dealt with excel formatting yet, but maybe [openpyxl](https://pythoninoffice.com/python-openpyxl-excel-formatting-cells/) will offer a more friendly interface than pandas.